# Disable pixmap background defined by GTK theme per application

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

For our (open source) fullscreen text editor we're changing background colors of `gtk.Window`, `gtk.Fixed`, etc. to custom colors. This works fine, but some [GTK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B) themes (e.g. [Mac4Lin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mac4lin/)) define background pixmaps instead of background colors for some widgets. Those background pixmaps won't go away when calling modify_bg() methods of those widgets.

I know I can set pixmaps with `bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = 'blabla.png'` and that I can define my own gtkrc overrides with gtk.rc_parse_string(). But I don't know how to unset `bg_pixmap[NORMAL]`.

So, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ofcourse Mac4Lin uses pixmaps for more granular appearance to match MAC look.
Well to disable those backgroud you dont need to override it.

if you want background pixmap as its parent's, set it as

```
bg_pixmap[state] = "<parent>"
```

and to disable set it as

```
bg_pixmap[state] = "<none>"
```